# Image grayed out on copy image to clipboard and paste image to document writer

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to copy dicom image to clipboard and I got it worked for image with smaller width/height. If any of the width/height is larger then , on pasting the copied image to writer document , small portion of the image is grayed out.

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.contentEditable = true;
var img1 = document.createElement('img');       
html2canvas($(".image"), {
    width     :  2000,
    height    : 500,
     logging: true, 
     letterRendering: 1, allowTaint : false,
              useCORS: true ,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");                            
                  clipboard(canvas.toDataUrl("image/jpeg"));     
                          }
 });

function clipboard(uri){
         img1.src = uri;            
        d.appendChild(img1);
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        enter image description hereSelectText(d);      
        return;                         
}

function SelectText(element) {
        var doc = document;
        if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(element);
            range.select();console.log(range);
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);console.log(range);
        }
    }
```

Below provide the link that shows the issue. The bottom corner is grayed out instead its base64 is shown

https://imggmi.com/full/2019/5/15/083abcce2a4c72c3f2acb667ec74c9cd-full.png.html